# login in with form login and HWIOAuthBundle

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

I tried fulfill authorization via HWIOAuthBundle, but I have some problem. When i first registreret user via registration form then after logout, i tried login in via HWIOAuthBundle i have error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'userl@gmail.com' for key 'UNIQ_957A6479A0D96FBF'
```

I followed this  [post](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697).

I substituted

```
$user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => mb_strtolower($response->getEmail())));
```

on

```
$user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($response->getEmail());
```

But then,when i tried again login in via facebook, the page redirect me on registration form

my custom privider:

namespace My\UserBundle\Security\Core\User;

```
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseClass;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseClass
{

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
{
    $property = $this->getProperty($response);
    $username = $response->getUsername();

    //on connect - get the access token and the user ID
    $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();

    $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($service);
    $setter_id = $setter.'Id';
    $setter_token = $setter.'AccessToken';

    //we "disconnect" previously connected users
    if (null !== $previousUser = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($property => $username))) {
        $previousUser->$setter_id(null);
        $previousUser->$setter_token(null);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($previousUser);
    }

    //we connect current user
    $user->$setter_id($username);
    $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());

    $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
{


  //  return new Response(var_dump($response->getRealName()) );
   // $check = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyUserBundle:User')->findOneByEmail_canonical($response->getEmail());
    $username = $response->getUsername();

    $user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail(array($this->getProperty($response) => mb_strtolower($response->getEmail())));
    //when the user is registrating
    if (null === $user) {
        $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($service);
        $setter_id = $setter.'Id';
        $setter_token = $setter.'AccessToken';
        // create new user here
        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        $user->$setter_id($username);
        $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());
        //I have set all requested data with the user's username
        //modify here with relevant data
        $user->setUsername($response->getRealName());
        $user->setEmail($response->getEmail());
        $user->setPassword($username);
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
        return $user;
    }

    //if user exists - go with the HWIOAuth way
    $user = parent::loadUserByOAuthUserResponse($response);

    $serviceName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
    $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($serviceName) . 'AccessToken';

    //update access token
    $user->$setter($response->getAccessToken());

    return $user;
}

}
```

I need just add facebok_id and token in to database if user with the same email exist and then login in.
How resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to use this solution:

```
<?php

namespace My\UserBundle\Security\Core\User;

use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseClass;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseClass
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $username = $response->getUsername();

        $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($service);
        $setterId = $setter . 'Id';
        $setterToken = $setter . 'AccessToken';

        //disconnect previously connected user
        if (null !== $previousUser = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username))) {
            $previousUser->$setterId(null);
            $previousUser->$setterToken(null);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($previousUser);
        }

        //connect current user
        $user->$setterId($username);
        $user->$setterToken($response->getAccessToken());

        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $username = $response->getUsername();
        $email = $response->getEmail();

        $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username));
        if (null === $user) {
            $user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($email);

            $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
            $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($service);
            $setterId = $setter . 'Id';
            $setterToken = $setter . 'AccessToken';

            if (null === $user) {
                $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
                $user->$setterId($username);
                $user->$setterToken($response->getAccessToken());

                $user->setUsername($username);
                $user->setEmail($email);
                $user->setPassword($username);
                $user->setEnabled(true);
                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

                return $user;
            } else {
                $user->$setterId($username);
                $user->$setterToken($response->getAccessToken());

                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

                return $user;
            }
        }

        //if user exists - go with the HWIOAuth way
        $user = parent::loadUserByOAuthUserResponse($response);

        $serviceName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($serviceName) . 'AccessToken';

        //update access token
        $user->$setter($response->getAccessToken());

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank!I did somithing this, but my code dosn't work)

Comment: Mikhail Prosalov, i did exactly that before,that but i did replace $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username));
 on $user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail(($response->getEmail()); Why your mehtod work adn my no?)

Comment: At first we trying to find user by social network field (ex. googleId or facebookId). If first search fails, we'll try to find user by email and set social network id to User entity. If second search fails, we'll simply create new User and set social network id. In your method you've tried to find User by social network field and passed email as needle.

Comment: Just tested this myself on my own application and the only method you need to change (normally) is loadUserByOAuthUserResponse - nice work!